# How to find and combine/group array buddy value together into several array?

Tags: python, arrays, relationship

I have an big array named with **whoHasMe** as below:

```
whoHasMe:  [[0], [1], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4], [5], [6, 7, 8], [7], [6, 8]]
```

As we can notice, these

> whoHasMe[0] has relationship with whoHasMe[2]
>
> whoHasMe[1] has relationship with whoHasMe[3]
>
> whoHasMe[2] has relationship with whoHasMe[3]
>
> whoHasMe[4] has relationship with whoHasMe[3]
>
> whoHasMe[5] has relationship with whoHasMe[3]
>
> whoHasMe[6] has relationship with whoHasMe[7]
>
> whoHasMe[8] has relationship with whoHasMe[7]

How can we group it to become another new big array?

finalBigArray = [[0,1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8]]

**Note that:** The value of whoHasMe Array might change. Seeking for help on how to find it's relationship and build a final big array.

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: how has finalBigArray a connection with the relationships?

Comment: finalBigArray comes from the relationship of small arrays in whoHasMe. In small arrays, some arrays (Exp: whoHasMe[0]) has the value (Exp: '0') of other array (Exp: whoHasMe[2]). Therefore, both of them are combined into another new array and continue.

Comment: The "relationships" make sense but the rationale behind construction of finalBigArray is unclear. btw - these are lists; not arrays. Maybe you could show the code you're having trouble with. That might help

Comment: @AnikethMalyala I thought I understood until I started trying to write code to deal with it then realised that I have absolutely no clue what's going on here. I'm sure Jay Jay will enlighten us shortly

Comment: @AlbertWinestein Explaining "relationship". For Exp: Anna is with Emy; Agnes is with Emy; David is with Agnes; Angel is with Charles; Charles is with Brian, Nicol is with Cora. Therefore, we can create a final big list with [[Anna, Emy, Agnes, David], [Angel, Charles, Brian], [Nicol, Cora]]. Hope I have a clue how to solve this one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I can think of is to use [disjoint set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Here is a simple implementation:

```
class DisjointSet:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.root = list(range(n))

    def __getitem__(self, k):    # find root
        return k if self.root[k] == k else self[self.root[k]]

    def union(self, a, b):
        x, y = self[a], self[b]
        if x != y:
            self.root[y] = x
```

First, convert each list in the given list into a set:

```
lst = [[0], [1], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4], [5], [6, 7, 8], [7], [6, 8]]
lst = list(map(set, lst))
```

Then judge whether there is a relationship between each pair of combinations. If so, union their indices:

```
length = len(lst)
ds = DisjointSet(length)
for i in range(length):
    for j in range(i + 1, length):
        if lst[i] & lst[j]:
            ds.union(i, j)
```

> The two-layer loop in previous step can be simplified through `itertools.combinations`:
>
> ```
> from itertools import combinations
> for (i, s1), (j, s2) in combinations(enumerate(lst), 2):
>     if s1 & s2:
>         ds.union(i, j)
> ```

With the help of `defaultdict`, we union sets in the same set:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)
for i in range(length):
    d[ds[i]] |= lst[i]
```

Finally, convert the dictionary values to lists:

```
print(list(map(sorted, d.values())))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

---

**Update:**

I have slightly modified the disjoint set, converted recursion into a loop, and enabled it to support iteration through the `__getitem__` method and `__len__` method. The final code is as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations


class DisjointSet:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.root = [None] * n

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        root = self.root
        while (r := root[k]) is not None:
            k = r
        return k

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.root)

    def union(self, a, b):
        x, y = self[a], self[b]
        if x != y:
            self.root[y] = x


def my_merge(lists):
    lists = list(map(set, lists))
    ds = DisjointSet(len(lists))
    for (i, s1), (j, s2) in combinations(enumerate(lists), 2):
        if s1 & s2:
            ds.union(i, j)

    d = defaultdict(set)
    for r, s in zip(ds, lists):
        d[r] |= s

    return list(map(sorted, d.values()))
```

Some test:

```
import random

for _ in range(3):
    lst = [sorted(random.randint(0, 50) for _ in range(random.randint(1, 6))) for _ in range(5)]
    print(f'lists:  {lst}')
    print(f'result: {my_merge(lst)}')
```

Output:

```
lists:  [[21, 26, 42, 44, 47], [4, 27, 40, 49], [5, 20, 39, 50], [14, 40, 47], [6]]
result: [[4, 14, 21, 26, 27, 40, 42, 44, 47, 49], [5, 20, 39, 50], [6]]
lists:  [[14, 26], [22], [4], [18, 22, 33, 37], [4, 5, 13, 19, 38, 46]]
result: [[14, 26], [18, 22, 33, 37], [4, 5, 13, 19, 38, 46]]
lists:  [[9, 9, 21, 31, 41], [7, 9, 28, 35, 43], [13, 23, 37, 42, 45], [4, 14, 21, 25], [0, 12, 14, 39, 50]]
result: [[0, 4, 7, 9, 12, 14, 21, 25, 28, 31, 35, 39, 41, 43, 50], [13, 23, 37, 42, 45]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, sir. Your codes have initiated the methods or ideas to solve this problem and gave sight to others to improve and made it better.  Thank you and wish you and your family a nice day! :)

Comment: Thank you for the multiple times of modifications. Grateful with my full heart!

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with the previous answer, the following is the new corrected version, please correct me if there is a problem.
Specify a variable item as the first item of a nested list, iterate through the nested list, assign their combination to the first item if there is a list that can be combined with it, then delete the eligible item and go directly to the next loop, this will ensure that each loop can be combined once, if no valid combination is found when this loop ends, then the item is independent and it is If no valid combination is found at the end of the loop, then the item is independent and can be added to the result list and repeated in turn (this method may not be efficient for large amounts of data, look for other efficient solutions)

```
def merge(intervals):
    res = []
    while len(intervals):
        is_new = True
        item = intervals[0]
        for index in range(1, len(intervals)):
            if set(item) & set(intervals[index]):
                intervals[0] = list(set(item + intervals[index]))
                intervals.pop(index)
                is_new = False

                break
        if is_new:
            res.append(intervals[0])
            intervals = intervals[1:]

    return res


print(merge([[0], [1], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 10], [4], [5], [6, 7, 8], [7], [6, 3], [9, 10]]))
print(merge([[0], [1], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4], [5], [6, 7, 8], [7], [6, 8]]))


# Output
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [5]]
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [8, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: The code is bugged, I think we should iterate over each item of result instead of sorting and using only the last item of result, try the code with this input to see the bug: `merge([[0], [1], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 10], [4], [5], [6, 7, 8], [7], [6, 3], [9, 10]])`

Comment: A minimal example of getting the wrong result: `[[2, 3], [0, 2], [1]]`, result should be `[[0, 2, 3], [1]]` but get `[[0, 2], [1], [2, 3]]`.

Comment: Indeed, since I want to avoid repeated traversals, I'll reconsider the modification options